# Recurring billing variable amount without storing credit card information

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway, authorize.net, payment-processing, recurring-billing

I have implemented few payment websites using PayPal Standard, PayPal Website Pro, PayPal Express and Authorize.Net.

Now I'm implementing a website which requires recurring billing. My only problem is **variable amount**, since I **do not store credit card** information, and **amount is not fixed** in each cycle.

Can we use either PayPal or Authorize.Net for my project? If not, could you please recommend any reliable payment gateway ($US for payment, and gateway located in US please) for that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. PayPal calls ProcessReferencePayment.

At first, I need to charge the credit card using ***DoDirectPayment***, and store the successful transaction number.

After that, I just call ***DoReferenceTransaction*** along with OrderTotal and ReferenceID (the previous transaction number).

DoReferenceTransactionRequestDetailsType

DoReferenceTransactionReq

Comment: Terminology varies between processors, but the basic idea you are looking for is "credit card tokenization". Both Paypal and Authorize offer this solution ("reference transaction" in Paypal terminology, "CIM" in Authorize terminology as John answered above).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a service like [Authorize.Net's Customer Information Manager (CIM)](http://developer.authorize.net/api/cim/) to store the credit card and billing information for you and then you create your own scheduling engine that charges against the payment method you have stored for them using CIM. CIM also allows you to make off-cycle payments at any time as well.

Comment: Can i use CIM except scheduling engine.Like,If customer made payment once and for next time he/she just have to enter unique identifier for payment except all the credit card information.

Comment: Yes. As long as you can identify who they are, and you saved their unique identifier returned to you by Authorize.Net, you can charge them at any time you want to without having to ask for *any* information from them.

Answer (score 0):

Well the variable amount to bill shouldn't be a problem if you can put together whatever formula would be used in code.  However if you aren't storing the actual credit card info (and I can understand why), then I don't see how you'd be able to charge the customer every month.  Normally you need a credit card or bank information to do a direct transfer.

If you absolutely cannot store the information, then the only thing I can imagine is putting together an automated calculation and notification system that can send the customer an email with a link that brings them to a form so they can enter the information as simply as possible.  Otherwise you'll need to save their credit card info somewhere secure and simply bill them every month, which isn't uncommon.

Comment: You can do a fixed amount (my understanding) recurring billing using PayPal Express without storing credit card info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into PayPal's IPN variables?

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside

Typically you have to cancel then reapprove a new subscription... but perhaps you can use the variables some how to do that programmatically.